# Should I use the same AddThis tag on multiple sites?

Tags: addthis

I have an [AddThis](https://www.addthis.com/) for one site:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ripper234">
</script>
```

Now I logged into AddThis and wanted to get my tag again, I saw it changed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ripper234">
</script>
```

Should I use the same tag I got before, or the new tag? What's the difference? Is 250/300 the internal version number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use it on every site. On my site its 200. It probably indicates the script. There are different appearances. With larger and smaller icon etc...

Comment: Right, I forgot about the different styles you can choose.